# Why are the poles of a magnet reversed when a magnet is split into two?

Tags: magnetic-fields

This question may be odd, but today i noticed something when my little magnet split into two pieces.

The poles reversed, so they could not get into "one piece" again (because the poles was reversed).

What is the physical explanation of this?

Comment: I found this: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080117085143AANrpah The "best answer" there seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I think you should clarify how it was split into two pieces, and what type of magnet? the ones for the refrigerator? Those have the north and south pole on the two sides that stick to the refrigerator. If they break they will be two magnets that will have north next to north and south next to south, and therefore repel.

Comment: It was the refrigerator magnets. And thanks. I think thats the answer, why they repel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This question may be odd, but today i noticed something when my little magnet split into two pieces.

As you clarified in the comments to the question, it was a refrigerator magnet. Those magnets have the poles on the flat sides, so that they stick to the iron metal of the doors. When they break it will be into two flat pieces, which will  have north next to north and south next to south, and therefore repel .

> The poles reversed, so they could not get into "one piece" again (because the poles was reversed).

No, the poles did not reverse because the break cuts perpendicularly the north and south surfaces.